# JQuery Image slider not sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

It seems that I cannot get my slider to slide for some reason...

Here is the **HTML**:

```
<div id="slider"><!--THE WHOLE DIV WITH TWO IMAGES AS EXAMPLE-->
<img src="1.jpg" id="1" />
<img src="2.jpg" id="2" />
</div>
```

Here is the **CSS**:

```
#slider{
width: 1200px;
height: 400px;
}
#slider>img{
width: 1200px;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
display: none
}
```

Here is the **Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slider>Img#1").fadeIn(300);
startslider();
});

function startslider(){
count = $("#slider>Img").size();

loop = setInterval(function(){

    if(sliderNext > count){
    sliderNext = 1;
    sliderInt = 1;
    }
    else{
    document.write("Error!");
    }

    $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
    $("$slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext= sliderNext+1;

}, 3000)
}

</script>
```

Please tell me where I've made a mistake, so I can learn from it as I still consider myself a beginner in JS/JQuery and would like to learn from my mistakes to improve my skills.

Thank You!

Comment: You have an error at $("$ it should be an # not a $

Comment: and tag "img" in lowercase

Answer (score 2):

Replace all the `Img` in your code by `img` and dollar sign `$` by `#` in :

```
$("$slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
___^_______^
```

Should be :

```
$("#slider>img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slider>img#1").fadeIn(300);
  startslider();
});

function startslider(){
  count = $("#slider>img").size();

  loop = setInterval(function(){

    if(sliderNext > count){
      sliderNext = 1;
      sliderInt = 1;
    }
    else{
      console.log("Error!");
    }

    $("#slider>img").fadeOut(300);
    $("#slider>img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext= sliderNext+1;

  }, 3000)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"><!--THE WHOLE DIV WITH TWO IMAGES AS EXAMPLE-->
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-5.jpg" id="1" />
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" id="2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Another silly typo ! :(
Thank you Zakaria that did help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#slider>img#1").fadeIn(300);
   startslider();
});

function startslider(){
   count = $("#slider img").size();

   loop = setInterval(function(){

   if(sliderNext >count){
       sliderNext = 1;
       sliderInt = 1;
    }else{
      //document.write("Count "+count+" / slidernext ="+sliderNext);
    }

    $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
    $("#slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext= sliderNext+1;

   }, 3000)
}
```